# RxAndroid: Retrofit doesn't work on the second time?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxAndroid and Retrofit for httpRequest, my code is as below:

```
          OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging)
                    .authenticator(new DigestAuthenticator())
                    .build();
            // retrofit with custom client
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(NetUtil.getServerBaseUrl())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
            ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiEndpoints.class);


    CustomerSubscriber mSubscriber = new CustomerSubscriber(); 

apiService.checkAccount(mUser.getEmail()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(mSubscirber);


    //Retrofit   
     @Headers({
                "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"
        })
        @HEAD("/account")
        Observable<Result<Void>> rxHeadAccount(
                @Query("email") String encryptedEmail);
```

My scenario like this: every time when I click the button "apiService.checkAccount()" method will be triggered. The first time:click button, the httpRequest is sent and I can get response

However, click the second time, no httpRequest was sent and the logs shows " **I/Choreographer: Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**"

However if I change code to

```
apiService.checkAccount(mUser.getEmail()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Result<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Result<Void> voidResult) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The Retrofit works very well, it can send HttpRequest as many times as your want?

Looks like the "Subscriber" can't be one instance?

Why, Any idea about it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Once an observable emits a terminal event (a complete or error event) it is not going to emit any more events (see [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)). Each call to `apiService.checkAccount(mUser.getEmail())` creates a new observable to which you can subscribe with a subscriber. This creates a subscription.

You probably want to store your subscription objects and `unsubscribe` from them when you're done.

Comment: However, In this first part code :  "apiService.checkAccount(mUser.getEmail()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(mSubscirber);", I do "mSubscirber.unsubscirbe()" after "onComplete", the second click still doesn't work